# "tunable" trapdoor function

Tags: trapdoor

We know that a trapdoor function $f()$ is easy to compute in its original direction $y=f(x)$ while finding its inverse $x=f^{-1}(y)$ requires a secret information: without that *trapdoor* inverting $f()$ is hard: let's say it requires applying $f()$ to many preimages $x$ until the required image $y$ is found, so it's something like $O(2^{|x|})$

Do exist any "tunable" trapdoor function, meaning a trapdoor for which:

1. a **partial** trapdoor can offer a complexity gain in inversion without making it definitely easy as a **full** trapdoor would do
2. it's possible to tune how much partial the trapdoor is, to decide the complexity gain of the inversion?

Comment: The obvious solution is using $2^k$ trapdoor functions ( from a family ) and merging them with a final trapdoor function. If you let them learn $2^\ell$ of them then you lost $k=\ell$ - bit security.

Comment: you mean "lost $k-l$ bit of security", right? And I don't get the need for the merging trapdoor function.. could you provide any actual example, please?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, sorry.